# S-M-* commands aren't recognized by Emacs

Tags: arch-linux, x11, emacs, xmodmap

I've noticed commands like `M->` (end-of-buffer) and `M-S-<right arrow>` (org-meta-right) aren't being recognized by Emacs. This was confirmed by describing key bindings using `C-h k`, which showed function assigned to `M-.`.

I'm using stock Emacs 24.3 (gui) on an up-to-date Arch Linux system running the latest version of Xorg (rootless). The issue is persistent across window managers, so I don't think it is a window manager issue. Also, the only modifications of made to my key map are:

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
setxkbmap -option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

I used key-mon to confirm that M-S- could be recognized by X. It appeared that it could. However, I also installed conkeror and found that it too wouldn't receive the key combination, so I think it must be a problem with my X server.

What else can I try to resolve this issue?

Typing `xmodmap -pke` reveals these NoSymbol regions of my keymap. Could they be the culprit?

```
keycode  36 = Return NoSymbol Return
keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
```

Using the command:

> setxkbmap -print -verbose 10

gives the following output:

```
    Setting verbose level to 10
    locale is C
    Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
    Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
    Success.
    Applied rules from evdev:
    rules:      evdev
    model:      thinkpad
    layout:     us
    options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,ctrl:nocaps,grp:alt_shift_toggle
    Trying to build keymap using the following components:
    keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
    types:      complete
    compat:     complete
    symbols:    pc+us+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)+ctrl(nocaps)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)
    geometry:   thinkpad(us)
    xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include   "pc+us+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)+ctrl(nocaps)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)" };
        xkb_geometry  { include "thinkpad(us)"  };
```

Comment: What do you mean by unrecognized? If you type `C-h k M-s-<right>` and you get the message `M-s-<right>` is undefined, then emacs recognizes the keybinding but it's not bound to any command. Use local/global-set-key to bind it. `M-s-<right>` is unbound on emacs 24.3.1 (in org mode) for me too. `M->` should work out of the box, but maybe it's easier to just define it instead of tracking down whats wrong.

Comment: What happens if you press these keys in Emacs? What happens if you press these keys in `xev`?

Comment: see updates. I did try defining `M->` as well, but Emacs still wouldn't let me type it.

Comment: Note, that by S I mean shift, not super which I denote by a lowercase s.  M-S-<right> should be bound to the aptly named `(org-shiftmetaright)` and it is on my copy of Emacs 24.3 on CentOS 6.3 at work.

Comment: Another example of a key binding I can't reach is `M-$` such as for `flyspell-mode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grp:alt_shift_toggle was somehow added to my Xorg configuration. Removing the line from 10-keyboard.conf and restarting X removed the undesired behavior.